# Can a subset of Natural numbers be uncountable?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I was trying some practice questions on Real Analysis. I can't seem to solve this one:

Let $ X := \{A \subset \Bbb{N} :$ both $A$ and $A^c$ are infinite$\}$. Prove that $X$ is uncountable.

From what I have studied about (un)countable sets is that the subset of a countable set can never be uncountable. It is known that $\Bbb{N}$ is a countable set. So how can such an $X$ exist which is a subset of $\Bbb{N}$ and is also uncountable?

Comment: $X$ is NOT a subset of $\mathbb N$. $X$ is a subset of the powerset of $\mathbb N$.

Comment: I dont understand. Doesn't $\{A \subset \Bbb{N} \}$ mean that it is a subset of $\Bbb{N}$? Maybe I'm missing out something because of the notation. Can you please explain?

Comment: A *set* **of** *subsets* of natural numbers is not the same thing as a subset of the natural numbers.

Comment: It is a collection of subsets, not just one subset.

Comment: With the brackets, it means nothing.  Without the brackets, it means A is proper subset of N..  @ElTikki

Comment: @WilliamElliot depending on the author, $\subset$ does not necessarily imply proper subset, just merely subset.  With the brackets (*and that meaning of $\subset$*), $\{A\subset \Bbb N\}$ would be the power set of $\Bbb N$.

Comment: @JMoravitz.  It is not a well formed term.

Comment: @ElTikki Sloppy thinking.  You correctly observe that $A$ is a subset of the naturals, then you refer to that as “it” and then leap to the conclusion that $X$ is a subset of the naturals.  Those are two different “it”s!  $X$ is a set of possible values of $A$, and $A$ is set of naturals.

Comment: @WilliamElliot If "*its not a wellformed term*" is in reference to $\{A\subset \Bbb N\}$, note that $\{A\subseteq \Bbb N\}=\{A~:~A\subseteq \Bbb N\} = \{A\subseteq \Bbb N~:~1=1\}$., this is the same as how some people would notate the set of even natural numbers as $\{x\in\Bbb N~:~\exists k\in\Bbb N~\text{s.t.}~x=2k\}$., We first give an arbitrary name to an element, say what parent set it belongs to, then give a condition to whether or not it is included.

Comment: I get it now. Thanks guys. I wasn't looking at the fact that $X$ is a collection of values of $A$

Comment: { A : A subset N }, which is P(N) is the only well formed term.  The rest are slang.

Answer (score 1):

Show the number of finite subsets of N is countable.
Show the number of subsets of N with finite complement is countable.
Show X is all the subsets of N not mentioned above.
Show there are uncountable many subsets of N.
Show us the rest of the proof that X is uncountable.

Riddle of the day:  if a set is uncountable, does that mean it doesn't count?